# cisco vpn client driver error

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

Hi I am a Windows 7 enterprise ed user, trying to connect to Cisco AnyConnect secure mobility client and It gives out the "VPN Client driver encountered error" Followed by unable to establish secure connection with the specified gateway message. This is the error log which I get.

```
[2/11/2015 12:24:02 PM] Posture Assessment: Active
[2/11/2015 12:24:02 PM] Posture Assessment: Initiating...
[2/11/2015 12:24:04 PM] Please enter your username and password.
[2/11/2015 12:24:23 PM] User credentials entered.
[2/11/2015 12:24:28 PM] Establishing VPN session...
[2/11/2015 12:24:32 PM] Checking for profile updates...
[2/11/2015 12:24:32 PM] Checking for product updates...
[2/11/2015 12:24:35 PM] Checking for customization updates...
[2/11/2015 12:24:35 PM] Performing any required updates...
[2/11/2015 12:24:35 PM] Establishing VPN session...
[2/11/2015 12:24:35 PM] Establishing VPN - Initiating connection...
[2/11/2015 12:24:38 PM] Establishing VPN - Examining system...
[2/11/2015 12:24:38 PM] Establishing VPN - Activating VPN adapter...
[2/11/2015 12:24:38 PM] Establishing VPN - Attempting to repair VPN adapter...
[2/11/2015 12:24:38 PM] Disconnect in progress, please wait...
[2/11/2015 12:24:41 PM] Connection attempt has failed.
[2/11/2015 12:24:43 PM] Ready to connect.
```

I tried all possible solutions on the internet. From disabling routing and remote services(it was already disabled), unchecked sharing in network center, Checked registry display name(it was correct too). Also checked select Allow service to interact with the desktop.. Please help. I tried everything. Uninstalling and reinstalling is not an option since I dont have a cisco login cred and this is my office laptop. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This problem sounds a lot like the "Failed to Enable Virtual Adapter" error I've encountered. It happens because the original adapter naming interferes with the driver detection.

To fix this error, go to the Registry key: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CVirtA** and change the **DisplayName** value to **Cisco Systems VPN Adapter for 64-bit Windows** .  Any name should do as long as it has no special characters.